# How to connect AFC terminal on Crystal Oscillator

Tags: datasheet, afc

I'm thinking of using a Temperature compensated crystal oscillator in my next project, specifically the [TXC 7L-38.400MBS-T](http://www.txccrystal.com/images/pdf/7l.pdf)

[image: TXC TXCO 7L]

This device has an AFC (Automatic Frequency Control) terminal, but no advice is given in the datasheet about how to connect this, and I can't find any information anywhere else on the web or on any other datasheets for other TXCOs.

What should I do with the AFC terminal? Leave it floating? Ground it?

Answer (score 2):

It's right there in the data sheet on the page you linked: -

[image]

Centre voltage is 1.4V and this I take to mean as the voltage (if applied) would do nothing to the factory setting i.e. it stays at the same frequency.

Note that there is a control range of 7 to 16 ppm per volt and this means if you lifted the voltage from 1.4V to 2.4 volts you'll probably offset the frequency by about 11 ppm or 11Hz per MHz - if it's a 50MHz xtal it'll move 550 Hz. Conversely if you took the 1.4V down to 0.4V, the frequency would nominally reduce by 550Hz in 50MHz.

What to do if you don't use it - be prepared to put a potential divider from the supply rail and ground to that pin, roughly generating 1.4Vdc BUT, there's a fair chance it'll work open circuited just fine.

Comment: Thanks Andy. Re: your last paragraph. That's exactly what I'm asking. Do I *have* to connect it? And if I do, is a potential divider enough? What's the current in to / out of that pin? I.E. does it need to be buffered?

Comment: I'd imagine a couple of 2k2 forming a pot divider would work fine. Maybe put 100n cap to 0v too but it'll prob work without anything.

Answer (score 2):

It would be a good idea to follow Andy's suggestion of putting a divider in place. You could always leave the spots unpopulated, but I don't think that will turn out to be an option.

Here's what the input circuit *probably* looks like (I say probably because it's a different [manufacturer](http://www5.epsondevice.com/en/quartz/library/about_osc/osc01_e.html), but they tend to be very similar).

[image]

As you can see, the input DC level is essentially floating except for leakage through the varactor diode, crystal and load capacitor. The resistor is probably hundreds of K ohms.

If you put a divider from the oscillator supply pins that yields 1.4V you should get nominal voltage, I don't think the resistance is critical, maybe 10K-ish resistors. A bypass cap as Andy suggests directly to the ground pin on the TCXO if you're really worried about phase noise.